# `print` function for an object with two different constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class `Line` with two different constructors:

```
// constructor - two points
Line::Line(Point& p1l, Point& p2l)
: p1(p1l), p2(p2l) {}

// constructor - point and vector
Line::Line(Point& pl, Vector& dirvec)
: p(pl), v(dirvec) {}
```

Now I am trying to implement a `print` function but have problems with it. Since, there are two constructors with two different sets of parameters, I need to know in advance which constructor was called to create a `Line`, which I try to print. But I do not know how to check it. Parameters of the constructors are objects of other classes, which have their own `print` functions.

```
// print function
void Line::print() const {
    cout << "Line[";
    p1.print();
    cout << ", ";
    if (p2) {
        p2.print();
    }
    else if (v) {
        v.print();
    }

    cout << "]";
}
```

I tried to check directly if the parameters of the constructors exist but it does not work that way - I need to initialise an object inside the `print` function which is a wrong logic.

What is the best way to implement such a print function?

Comment: Why couldn't you just hold two pointers or pointer with a vector? You could easily calculate the second point or the vector in constructor.

Comment: @soon: good point, thank you. If there is no better way, I will do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your class holds four fields: `p1`, `p2` for the first constructor and `p` with `v` for the second.

This approach is bad, since you should disambiguate between uninitialized fields every time you operate with them (not only in `print` function, but **every time**).

I suggest you choose one of the following solutions:

### Hold `start` and `end` points.

You have to change your constructors like the following:

```
Line::Line(const Point& start, const Point& end)
: start_(start), end_(end) {}

// constructor - point and vector
// You should implement operator+ (or a method) for vector and point.
Line::Line(Point& start, Vector& direction)
: start_(start), end_(start + direction) {}
```

### Hold `start` point and `direction` vector:

```
// Point - Point should return a Vector. Or you could implement a Vector(Point, Point)
Line::Line(const Point& start, const Point& end)
: start_(start), direction_(end - start) {}

Line::Line(Point& start, Vector& direction)
: start_(start), direction_(direction) {}
```

Comment: I was writing something similar, +1. Based on the performance/memory needs, it could also make sense to store all three of `start`, `end`, `direction` (some algorithms work better with one representation, some with the other).

Comment: Does that `_` in `start_` mean something or is it just a name of the variable?

Comment: @Alexandr, It is just a matter of style - I always mark private variables with the underscore.

Comment: @Angew, Yes, I agree with you. But it mostly depends on the real problem. Also, we should be careful when changing the state of an object with redundant information. Making `Line` persistent may be a good idea in this case, but it requires a lot of object creations. So, we should make some performance tests before deciding the solution.

Comment: It looks an interesting approach. Thank you.

Comment: If it is affordable to lose the original 2 points / point+vector in favor of unified initialization, then this indeed is a better solution than having a member variable indicating how the object was initialized.

Comment: @SergeRogatch, what do you mean by "if it is affordable"? What can be the problem here?

Comment: @Alexandr, the problem can be that you want to see the object printed the way it is initialized, but you lose this information in this approach. If you choose to always store e.g. 2 points, then initialize with a point and a direction, then print the object, you will not see the original point and a direction - instead, you will see 2 points. It depends on your requirements whether that behavior is affordable or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can save in a member variable the information indicating which constructor was called.

```
class Line
{
    enum class ConstructionInfo : uint8_t
    {
        NONE = 0,
        TWO_POINTS = 1,
        POINT_DIRVECTOR = 2
    }
    ConstructionInfo _ci = ConstructionInfo::NONE;
}
```

Then in your constructors initialize this variable:

```
// constructor - two points
Line::Line(Point& p1l, Point& p2l)
: p1(p1l), p2(p2l), _ci(ConstructionInfo::TWO_POINTS) {}

// constructor - point and vector
Line::Line(Point& pl, Vector& dirvec)
: p(pl), v(dirvec), _ci(ConstructionInfo::POINT_DIRVECTOR) {}
```

And then in the print() method:

```
switch(_ci)
{
case ConstructionInfo::TWO_POINTS:
    // print 2 points
    break;
case ConstructionInfo::POINT_DIRVECTOR:
    // print a point and a directing vector
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use an enumerated type to indicate the type of object. The enumerated variable could be set differently in each of the constructors.

```
// constructor - two points
Line::Line(Point& p1l, Point& p2l)
: p1(p1l), p2(p2l), type(POINT_BASED) {}

// constructor - point and vector
Line::Line(Point& pl, Vector& dirvec)
: p(pl), v(dirvec), type(POINT_BASED) {}

// print function
void Line::print() const {
    cout << "Line[";
    p1.print();
    cout << ", ";
    if (type == POINT_BASED) {
        p2.print();
    }
    else if (type == VECTOR_BASED) {
        v.print();
    }

    cout << "]";
}
```

However, perhaps you should also consider splitting the class into two classes derived from a BaseLine - each with their own print function - if they really are that different.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It may be a good idea, but I am afraid that I will be copy-pasting a lot between them, since the methods will be the same for both classes.

Comment: Remember that for common code, you can always call common base class functions from your virtual functions which cuts down the amount of code copying. You only need to derive where necessary.